# output as a single row from dhcp output

Tags: parsing, powershell

I'm running dhcp query through powershell. I am getting the information I want to see but not in a format I need.
Sample:
data I'm working with the command:

```
netsh dhcp server \\dhcpserver scope 10.0.1.0 show clientsvq
```

gets output of

```
10.0.1.21    - 255.255.255.0  -00-23-7d-e9-45-58   -2/19/2016 5:13:50 PM    -D -BUILD-01.example.com -NonQuarantined -INACTIVE -No
10.0.1.22    - 255.255.255.0  -00-23-7d-e9-54-38   -2/19/2016 5:13:55 PM    -D -BUILD-02.example.com -NonQuarantined -INACTIVE -No
10.0.1.23    - 255.255.255.0  -00-23-7d-e8-cf-80   -6/11/2016 11:30:30 AM   -D -BUILD-03.example.com -NonQuarantined -INACTIVE -No
```

What I want as an output is this:

```
10.0.1.21 00237de94558 BUILD-01.example.com
10.0.1.22 00237de95438 BUILD-02.example.com
10.0.1.23 00237de8cf80 BUILD-03.example.com
```

tried formatting the output by extracting the desired column and stripping off the special characters, command:

```
netsh dhcp server \\dhcpserver scope 10.0.1.0 show clientsvq | findstr example.com | foreach {"$(($_ -split '\s+',10)[0,3])" -replace "\-",""; "$(($_ -split '\s+',10)[8])" -replace "^-","";}
```

I get the following output format:

```
10.0.1.21 00237de94558
BUILD-01.example.com
10.0.1.22 00237de95438
BUILD-02.example.com
10.0.1.23 00237de8cf80
BUILD-03.example.com
```

Can someone point me out where my logic is flawed? I can't seemed to get to the much needed correct output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that seems to work. I simplified what you attempted by storing the array returned by the `-split` operator in a variable to avoid the unwinding that would happen if it was sent down the pipeline. This way we can access each column in a straightforward way. Note, to simplify, I just replaced your dhcp command with `$dhcpcommand`:

```
$dhcpcommand | select-string example.com | %{$cols = @($_ -split '\s+'); "$($cols[0]) $($cols[3] -replace '-','') $($cols[8])"}
```

Comment: Sir, you are my hero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to parse the output and return rich objects instead of text:

```
netsh dhcp server \\dhcpserver scope 10.0.1.0 show clientsvq  | foreach  {

    $values = ($_ -split '\s+-')[0,2,5]

    if($values[0] -as [ipaddress])
    {
         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           IPAddress = [ipaddress]$values[0].Trim()
           MAC = $values[1].Trim() -replace '-'
           Name = $values[2].Trim()
        }
    }    
}
```